# kineticjs move element to another layer on mousedown

Tags: kineticjs

i know that dragOnTop was recently introduced, but i want use a specific layer, not the always on top auto generated one. So I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jure/EwrkQ/

```
darthVaderImg.on("mousedown", function() {
    this.moveTo(temp);
    this.setDraggable(true);
    //...
}
```

But it doesn't work! It seems that when i change layer i loose the mouse event hook... Help please!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the problem stems from the object initial state of draggable: false

This is my solution so far, hope it brings you closer: http://jsfiddle.net/EwrkQ/4/

```
    darthVaderImg.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'move';
    });
    darthVaderImg.on('mousedown', function() {
      this.moveTo(temp);
      this.setDraggable(true);
      this.simulate('dragstart');
      layer.draw();
      temp.draw();
    });
    darthVaderImg.on('dragmove', function() {
      temp.draw();
    });
    darthVaderImg.on("dragend",function(){
        //this.setDraggable(false);
        this.moveTo(layer);
        layer.draw();
        temp.draw();
        this.off("mouseup");
      });

    darthVaderImg.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the help, however the following example (running Kineticjs 4.0.1) works enabling drag onmousedown, i'll investigate further for another solution http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-drag-and-drop-stress-test-with-1000-shapes/

Comment: yeah, refactor your code completely so you don't have to use mouse down.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since dragOnTop moves your item to a temporary layer, then you should disable that functionality.

```
 darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({... , dragOnTop: false, ...});
```

That should work.

Comment: EliteOctagon, can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link for kineticjs move element to another layer on mousedown

http://codedbot.com/questions/3016590/kineticjs-move-element-to-another-layer-on-mousedown